# Create a fake or dummy virtual printer on HP-UX

Tags: unix, printer, hp-ux

I need to set up a fake printer in HP-Unix.. It doesn't need to do any printing but it needs to act as a printer so that an application thinks there is a printer.

Can some help me with a script for that?

Answer (score 1):

```
# create printer
lpadmin -p printer1 -v /dev/null -m HPLaserJet 

# make it working
accept printer1 
enable printer1 

# Make it a default printer for the whole system (if necessary)
lpadmin -d printer1 

# remove the printer
lpadmin -x printer1
```

Hope this helps